# How can I style an HTML checkbox's text?

Tags: html, css

With this input checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox">Click moi!
```

...and this CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
    color:green;
    font-family: Consolas, Baskerville, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

input[type=checkbox]:hover {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #1300ff;
}
```

...the hover bit works fine (the checkbox itself changes), but the color / font of the text ("Click moi!") is not affected by setting color and font-family.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QRBEx/

How can I affect the text attributes via CSS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The text should be within a `label`. Add a `for` attribute to attach it to the checkbox too.

[**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/a545M/) - it works.

```
<input id="checkbox" type="checkbox"/><label for="checkbox">Click me</label>
```

Then change the CSS:

```
label {
    color:green;
    font-family: Consolas, Baskerville, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

input[type=checkbox]:hover {
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #1300ff;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

First, mark up the text correctly. You have a label for the input, use a label element.

```
<input type=checkbox id=myCheckbox> <label for=myCheckbox> Click moi! </label>
```

Then, make the assumption that the label for a checkbox will always immediately follow that checkbox in the markup and use the adjacent sibling combinator:

```
input[type="checkbox"] + label {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<input>` tag does not have an end tag - it's a self-closing tag. So the text next to it is not part of it. You need to style the text separately as its own element, like a `<label>`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

One good idea is to use a `<span>` tag:

```
<style>
    #cb_span{color:green;}
</style>
<input type="checkbox"><span id="cb_span">Click moi!</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

This text is not the part of the checkbox. It's the normal floating text and it belongs to its container (which is also checkbox's container). If you have your `chackbox` + `text` pair wrapped in some container e.g.

```
<div id="container">
    <input type="checkbox">Click moi!
</div>
```

then you can add such CSS

```css
#container {
    color:green;
    font-family: Consolas, Baskerville, 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The text itself isn't part of the `input` element.
By instead placing the text in an HTML element and using a bit of CSS trickery, we can change the text like in the included fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QRBEx/8/

Answer (score 0):

The text needs to be in  a label. create a label for the checkbox.
i hope this helps

Comment: This is not comment box

Comment: How would this help? There's a 4 year old *accepted* answer which not only says the same thing, but also provides accompanying code. What exactly do you think you are contributing?